# Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base

Tags: android, jcenter, maven-central

```
Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

I could connect to the host.

```
gongzelong:android gongzelong$ nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:1086 jcenter.bintray.com 443 -v
Connection to jcenter.bintray.com port 443 [tcp/https] succeeded!
^C
gongzelong:android gongzelong$ nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:1086 repo1.maven.org 443 -v
Connection to repo1.maven.org port 443 [tcp/https] succeeded!
^C
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone still experiences this. This happened to me and I realized [the referenced link](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml) was not the problem.

1. The link must be referenced in https
2. Make sure you have a good internet connection
3. Invalidate cache or clean flutter

It is also important to note that I can't access the referenced link directly on the browser. But the app was built successfully when I did the above-outlined steps.